# Two PostgreSQL 9.5 beta 2 - short replication howto

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Try configure native Bi-Direction (synchronous) replication between two postgresql 9.5 beta 2.

OS Ubuntu 14.04

Googled many documents and blogs, but still dont understand how can I configure postgresql.conf to start Bi-Direction replication

Any sample please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because there is no built-in support for bidirectional replication in PostgreSQL 9.5.

The [BDR project](http://bdr-project.org/docs/stable/) is an effort to develop mesh multimaster logical replication. It is based on 9.4. There is no plan to support 9.5; we intend to skip straight to 9.6 when it is released, and stay on 9.4 in the mean time.

There are external trigger-based tools that do multi-master for PostgreSQL 9.5, like [Londiste](http://skytools.projects.pgfoundry.org/skytools-3.0/) and [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Main_Page).

There's also [Postgres-XL](http://www.postgres-xl.org/) for full tightly-coupled multi-master but it hasn't been updated to 9.5 yet, and it's a separate modified PostgreSQL, not an add-on.

pglogical, which is derived from BDR, will hopefully provide full multimaster in future, but that's more like 9.6 timeframe.

Comment: so this information about 9.5 is no longer valid? http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/bdr-postgresql-present-future/

Comment: *"If all the patches required to run BDR (see below) get into PostgreSQL 9.5 it will be possible to run the BDR extension on a stock community version of PostgreSQL 9.5"*. They didn't, so it isn't. Most of the rest made it into 9.6 so we should be able to prep a BDR release on top of 9.6 when that's closer to being ready.